# add class (current) on menu item if It has particular url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've have a WordPress multisite. 
I need to add a class (`current`) on menu item if tt has the url:

```
www.mysite.com/clients
```

I tried this code but doesn't work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var url = $(location).attr('protocol')+"//"+$(location).attr('host')+"/clients/";
    $('li a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('current_page_item');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess selector is a bit off as url can be full and can be partial...with trailing slash or without. If you'd provide a piece of menu with links and the actual url you are in - it would be easier. But this might also do the trick:

```
    $("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass('current_page_item');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you try to modify the HTML, you should include the HTML in your post.

This is a wild guess but I'm guessing this could be a solution:

```
$('a[href="'+url+'"]').addClass('current_page_item');
```